# Remote desktop connection does not ask me for credentials

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

When I try to remote into my server from my PC a box comes up that asks me for my credentials, however no input boxes come up for me to give it my username and password.

Here is what I get,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Launch the RDC client and use Show Options to set up the default settings, there in the General tab you can set up the account that will be used to connect from now on by default

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxKDg.jpg

Comment: I've just tried that and still got the same box appearing asking me to enter my credentials

Comment: Modify on the registry the default settings for that connection:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default\Servers 

and look up for the IP address / FQDN of that specific connection, you can modify the UsenameHint value and set the user that you prefer

Comment: How do we go about doing this?

Comment: this happens to even new IP's I am entering

Answer (score 0):

Delete the default.rdp file from the documents folder.   This file is hidden, so, make sure "Show hidden files" in checked.